# How do I view grants on Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to view grants on redshifts.

I found [this view for postgres](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/quot-SHOW-GRANTS-FOR-username-quot-or-why-z-is-not-enough-for-me-td5714952.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_all_grants AS 
SELECT 
  use.usename as subject, 
  nsp.nspname as namespace, 
  c.relname as item, 
  c.relkind as type, 
  use2.usename as owner, 
  c.relacl, 
  (use2.usename != use.usename and c.relacl::text !~ ('({|,)' || use.usename || '=')) as public
FROM 
  pg_user use 
  cross join pg_class c 
  left join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace = nsp.oid) 
  left join pg_user use2 on (c.relowner = use2.usesysid)
WHERE 
  c.relowner = use.usesysid or 
  c.relacl::text ~ ('({|,)(|' || use.usename || ')=') 
ORDER BY 
  subject, 
  namespace, 
  item
```

Which doesn't work because the `::text` cast of `relacl` fails with the following:

```
ERROR: cannot cast type aclitem[] to character varying [SQL State=42846]
```

Modifying the query to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_all_grants AS 
SELECT 
  use.usename as subject, 
  nsp.nspname as namespace, 
  c.relname as item, 
  c.relkind as type, 
  use2.usename as owner, 
  c.relacl 
  -- , (use2.usename != use.usename and c.relacl::text !~ ('({|,)' || use.usename || '=')) as public
FROM 
  pg_user use 
  cross join pg_class c 
  left join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace = nsp.oid) 
  left join pg_user use2 on (c.relowner = use2.usesysid)
WHERE 
  c.relowner = use.usesysid 
  -- or c.relacl::text ~ ('({|,)(|' || use.usename || ')=') 
ORDER BY 
  subject, 
  namespace, 
  item
```

Allows the view to be created, but I'm concerned that this is not showing all relevant data.

How can I modify the view to work on redshift or is there an better/alternative way to view grants on redshift ?

**UPDATE:** Redshift has the HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE function to check grants. (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE.html))

Comment: What error do you get when you don't comment out those two lines? If it is definitely the cast that is failing, what is the type of the `relacl` column?

Comment: Updated with the actual error message from the cast.

Comment: Does `select 'postgres=arwdDxt/postgres'::aclitem::text` work OK? How about `select '{postgres=arwdDxt/postgres,=r/postgres}'::aclitem[]::text[]::text`? If those work, then you should be able to change `c.relacl::text` to `c.relacl::text[]::text`. If not, you'll need to find another way of looking inside the ACLs (or create a custom cast).

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, ``select 'anmediaextract01=arwdxt/anmediaextract01'::aclitem::text`` (note no 'D') fails with same error. Same with the other variant. Don't thnk it's possible to create custom casts in redshift btw.

Comment: Ah ha! - It seems that HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE function works on redshift:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE.html

Comment: Note that the HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE does not show privileges granted to groups which is why I had to build the query shown below.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Another variation be like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        schemaname
        ,objectname
        ,usename
        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS sel
        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ins
        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS upd
        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS del
        ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ref
    FROM
        (
        SELECT schemaname, 't' AS obj_type, tablename AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj FROM pg_tables
        WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal','pg_automv')
        UNION
        SELECT schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, viewname AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj FROM pg_views
        WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal','pg_automv')
        ) AS objs
        ,(SELECT * FROM pg_user) AS usrs
    ORDER BY fullobj
    )
WHERE (sel = true or ins = true or upd = true or del = true or ref = true)
and schemaname='<opt schema>'
and usename = '<opt username>';
```

Comment: I'm receiving `[3F000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: schema "pg_temp_12" does not exist;`, any idea on what can be wrong?

Answer (score 20):

Something along the lines off:

```
select tablename, 
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(tablename, 'select') as select,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(tablename, 'insert') as insert,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(tablename, 'update') as update,
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(tablename, 'delete') as delete, 
   HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(tablename, 'references') as references 
from pg_tables where schemaname='public' order by tablename;
```

gives me all I need.

Comment: I receive error message `[42P01][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "sql_features" does not exist;` :/

Answer (score 5):

A development on the answer from mike_pdb I came up with the following

```
 WITH object_list(schema_name,object_name,permission_info)
 AS (
    SELECT N.nspname, C.relname, array_to_string(relacl,',')
    FROM pg_class AS C
        INNER JOIN pg_namespace AS N
        ON C.relnamespace = N.oid
    WHERE C.relkind in ('v','r')
    AND  N.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema')
    AND C.relacl[1] IS NOT NULL
  ),
  object_permissions(schema_name,object_name,permission_string)
  AS (
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',1) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',2) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',3) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',4) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',5) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',6) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',7) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',8) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',9) FROM object_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,object_name, SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',10) FROM object_list
  ),
  permission_parts(schema_name, object_name,security_principal, permission_pattern)
  AS (
      SELECT
          schema_name,
          object_name,
          LEFT(permission_string ,CHARINDEX('=',permission_string)-1),
          SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(permission_string,'=',2),'/',1)
      FROM object_permissions
      WHERE permission_string >''
  )
SELECT
    schema_name,
    object_name,
    'GRANT ' ||
    SUBSTRING(
        case when charindex('r',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',SELECT ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('w',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',UPDATE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('a',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',INSERT ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('d',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',DELETE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('R',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',RULE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('x',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',REFERENCES ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('t',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',TRIGGER ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('X',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',EXECUTE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('U',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',USAGE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('C',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',CREATE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('T',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',TEMPORARY ' else '' end
    ,2,10000
    )
    || ' ON ' || schema_name||'.'||object_name
     || ' TO ' || security_principal
     || ';' as grantsql
FROM permission_parts

;
```

There are 3 common table expressions used here.

- object_list - Tables and views with their permissions array as a comma delimited string.
- object_permissions - schema/object (table or view) and a record per permission string.  Note that the SPLIT_PART function does not allow a dynamic part position so the assumption here is that there are no more than 10 users or groups assigned direct permissions
- permission_parts The schema/object, security principal to whom permissions are granted and the security attributes that are set.

As per mike_pdb's solution the individual permission characters are converted into a concatenated list of grants.  As we don't which grants will be used we use SUBSTRING from position 2 to discard the first comma in the list.

You can use exactly the same approach for scripting off schema permissions

```
WITH schema_list(schema_name, permission_info)
AS (
    SELECT nspname, array_to_string(nspacl,',')
    FROM pg_namespace
    WHERE nspacl[1] IS NOT NULL
    AND nspname NOT LIKE 'pg%' AND nspname NOT IN ('public','information_schema')
),
schema_permissions(schema_name,permission_string)
AS (
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',1) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',2) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',3) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',4) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',5) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',6) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',7) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',8) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',9) FROM schema_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT schema_name,SPLIT_PART(permission_info,',',10) FROM schema_list
),
permission_parts(schema_name, security_principal, permission_pattern)
AS (
    SELECT
        schema_name,
        LEFT(permission_string ,CHARINDEX('=',permission_string)-1),
        SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(permission_string,'=',2),'/',1)
    FROM schema_permissions
    WHERE permission_string >''
)
SELECT
    schema_name,
    'GRANT ' ||
    SUBSTRING(
        case when charindex('r',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',SELECT ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('w',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',UPDATE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('a',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',INSERT ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('d',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',DELETE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('R',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',RULE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('x',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',REFERENCES ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('t',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',TRIGGER ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('X',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',EXECUTE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('U',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',USAGE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('C',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',CREATE ' else '' end
      ||case when charindex('T',permission_pattern) > 0 then ',TEMPORARY ' else '' end
    ,2,10000
    )
    || ' ON SCHEMA ' || schema_name
     || ' TO ' || security_principal
     || ';' as grantsql
FROM permission_parts;
```

Answer (score 4):

The has_table_privilege function is handy, but doesn't always help in administration when you want to manage groups.  I morphed your original query to create grant scripts for specific users or groups.  This sample query can be easily morphed to accommodate your needs

```
select namespace||'.'||item as tablename , 
'grant ' || substring(
                case when charindex('r',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',select ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('w',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',update ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('a',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',insert ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('d',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',delete ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('R',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',rule ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('x',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',references ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('t',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',trigger ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('X',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',execute ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('U',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',usage ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('C',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',create ' else '' end 
              ||case when charindex('T',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),'group dw_developers=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',temporary ' else '' end 
           , 2,10000)
 || ' on '||namespace||'.'||item ||' to group dw_developers;' as grantsql
from 
(SELECT 
  use.usename as subject, 
  nsp.nspname as namespace, 
  c.relname as item, 
  c.relkind as type, 
  use2.usename as owner, 
  c.relacl 
 FROM 
  pg_user use 
  cross join pg_class c 
  left join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace = nsp.oid) 
  left join pg_user use2 on (c.relowner = use2.usesysid)
 WHERE 
  c.relowner = use.usesysid  
  and  nsp.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema')
 ORDER BY 
  subject,   namespace,   item 
 ) where relacl is not null
 and array_to_string(relacl, '|') like '%group dw_developers%' order by 1
```

Comment: ....this seems to have a () closing problem in it somewhere, but I haven't tried to track it down.

Comment: Wouldn't this only get ownership relationships? So, if I create (and own) a schema and grant access to a group, it wouldn't appear, right?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another useful query to view grants on schema (usage, create) by user that I created based on the query above by [@drtf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1628065/drtf):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        schemaname
        ,usename
        ,HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') AS usg
        ,HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'create') AS crt
    FROM
        (
        SELECT distinct(schemaname) FROM pg_tables
        WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
        UNION
        SELECT distinct(schemaname) FROM pg_views
        WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
        ) AS objs
        ,(SELECT * FROM pg_user) AS usrs
    ORDER BY schemaname
    )
WHERE (usg = true or crt = true)
--and schemaname='<opt schemaname>'
--and usename = '<opt username>';
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this a lot and finally came up with a solution that gives me just what I want to see.

```
WITH tabledef as (
    SELECT schemaname,
        't' AS typename,
        tablename AS objectname,
        tableowner as owner,
        schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullname
    FROM pg_tables
    UNION 
    SELECT schemaname,
        'v' AS typename,
        viewname AS objectname,
        viewowner as owner,
        schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullname
    FROM pg_views
),
res AS (
    SELECT t.*,
    CASE HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'select')
    WHEN true THEN u.usename
    ELSE NULL END AS sel,
    CASE HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'insert')
    WHEN true THEN u.usename
    ELSE NULL END AS ins,
    CASE HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'update')
    WHEN true THEN u.usename
    ELSE NULL END AS upd,
    CASE HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'delete')
    WHEN true THEN u.usename
    ELSE NULL END AS del,
    CASE HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'references')
    WHEN true THEN u.usename
    ELSE NULL END AS ref
    FROM tabledef AS t
    JOIN pg_user AS u
    ON HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'select') = true
        OR HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'insert') = true
        OR HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'update') = true
        OR HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'delete') = true
        OR HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(u.usename, t.fullname, 'references') = true
        OR t.owner = u.usename
    WHERE t.schemaname = 'analytics'
)
SELECT schemaname, objectname, owner, sel, ins, upd, del, ref FROM res
WHERE sel not in ('rdsdb', '<superuser>')
ORDER BY schemaname, objectname;
```

The two important lines - One which points which schema to scan for access

```
WHERE t.schemaname = 'analytics'
```

And - Second which discards superuser permissions (They have complete permission anyway) from the results.

```
WHERE sel not in ('rdsdb', '<superuser>')
```

Comment: It's work in 2021

Answer (score 2):

Because other proposed solutions have dependencies on pg tables and sometimes return odd error messages (reported in comments) I go with a more straightforward and manual approach:

```
select has_schema_privilege('my_user', 'my_schema', 'usage');
select has_table_privilege('my_user', 'my_schema.my_table', 'select');
```

which most of the times is good enough for me; based on:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE.html

All other permutations can be achieved based on docs and joining with other tables (e.g. `svv_table_info`, given that pg tables are not always reliable).