# How to query user group privileges in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

So in postgresql I can do something like:

```
SELECT has_table_privilege('myuser', 'mytable', 'select')
```

to see whether `myuser` has select access on `mytable`.  Is there something similar for user groups?  Basically, I'd like to be able to submit a query to see if a group has certain privileges on a specified table.

Thanks!

Comment: A group is essentially the same thing as a user. Did you try: `SELECT has_table_privilege('mygroup', 'mytable', 'select')`?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that.  On Redshift, at least, this is not valid

Answer (score 2):

You could make a simple function to query role privileges;

```
CREATE FUNCTION role_has_table_privilege(g NAME, tn NAME, pt NAME) 
RETURNS boolean AS 
 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.role_table_grants WHERE (grantee, table_name, privilege_type) IN (($1, $2, $3)));' 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

It basically just selects role table grants from information_schema.role_table_grants and matches with the parameters. Roles include both users and groups.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/427f4/1).

Note that in this very simple example has some limitations. For example, the values are case sensitive. That means the privilege type is called `INSERT`, not `insert`. Also, if you want to include `PUBLIC` permissions, you'll have to extend the function slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Joe's view looks like it was derived from [How do I view grants on Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741334/how-do-i-view-grants-on-redshift/21178589#21178589).  Note this other useful query for finding missing permissions where in this example I want to grant read privs to the select_group to objects that don't have it:

```
select 'grant select on '||namespace||'.'||item||' to group select_group;' from 
(
SELECT 
 use.usename as subject, 
 nsp.nspname as namespace, 
 c.relname as item, 
 c.relkind as type, 
 use2.usename as owner, 
 c.relacl 
FROM 
pg_user use 
cross join pg_class c 
left join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace = nsp.oid) 
left join pg_user use2 on (c.relowner = use2.usesysid)
WHERE 
c.relowner = use.usesysid  
and  nsp.nspname  NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema')
and ((array_to_string(relacl, '|') not like '%select_group%' or relacl is null)
    or 
   (array_to_string(relacl, '|') like '%select_group%' and CHARINDEX('r', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), 'select_group', 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) = 0 )
        )
and c.relkind   <> 'i'
ORDER BY  subject,   namespace,   item 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this question about Redshift or Postgres? If it's Redshift then Joachim Isaksson's answer will not work because Redshift does not support functions.

I use the follow view to see table permissions. It's loosely based on something from Redshift forum but unfortunately I didn't make a note of the source.

```
/* List of all Grants currently in place. */
CREATE VIEW admin.vw_table_grants
AS
SELECT   relacl
        ,'GRANT ' 
        || SUBSTRING(
           CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('r', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', SELECT'     ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('w', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', UPDATE'     ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('a', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', INSERT'     ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('d', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', DELETE'     ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('R', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', RULE'       ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('x', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', REFERENCES' ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('t', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', TRIGGER'    ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('X', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', EXECUTE'    ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('U', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', USAGE'      ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('C', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', CREATE'     ELSE '' END
        || CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('T', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', TEMPORARY'  ELSE '' END
           , 3,10000)
        || ' ON '|| namespace ||'.'|| item ||' TO '|| pu.groname ||' ;' AS grantsql
FROM    (SELECT      use.usename AS subject
                    ,nsp.nspname AS namespace
                    ,cls.relname AS item
                    ,cls.relkind AS type
                    ,use2.usename AS owner
                    ,cls.relacl
        FROM        pg_user     use 
        CROSS JOIN  pg_class    cls
        LEFT JOIN   pg_namespace nsp 
        ON          cls.relnamespace = nsp.oid 
        LEFT JOIN   pg_user      use2 
        ON          cls.relowner = use2.usesysid
        WHERE       cls.relowner = use.usesysid
        AND         nsp.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema')
        ORDER BY     subject
                    ,namespace
                    ,item ) 
JOIN    pg_group pu ON array_to_string(relacl, '|') LIKE '%'|| pu.groname ||'%' 
WHERE   relacl IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 2
```