# How to show Redshift Spectrum (external schema) GRANTS?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741334/how-do-i-view-grants-on-redshift) is useful to show Redshift GRANTS but doesn't show GRANTS over external tables / schema.

How to show external schema (and relative tables) privileges?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since that in external tables it is possible to only `select` data this one is enough to check `usage` permission over the external tables:

```
SELECT schemaname, tablename, usename,
       has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS usage
FROM SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES, pg_user AS usrs
WHERE schemaname = '<my-schema-name>'
  and usename = '<my-user>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvement over the version from @Vzzarr

```
SELECT DISTINCT schemaname, usrs.usename, 'usage' as privilege,
    has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS usage
FROM SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES, pg_user AS usrs
ORDER BY 1,2
```