# Error while querying user grants "relation "sql_features" does not exist"

Tags: amazon-redshift, user-permissions

I want to identify all the grants my Redshift user have on various objects in the schema for which I am using the following code, but getting the error.

```
SELECT
    u.usename,
    t.schemaname||'.'||t.tablename,
    has_table_privilege(u.usename,t.tablename,'select') AS user_has_select_permission
FROM
    pg_user u
CROSS JOIN
    pg_tables t
WHERE
    u.usename = 'userid'
```

> ERROR: 42P01: relation "sql_features" does not exist

Comment: where did you read that this world work on redshift? provide a link? (postgres <> redshift)

Comment: Did u mean 'would' instead of 'world' ? Because if not, I do not get the sarcasm :)

Comment: yes it was a typo and does not have any sarcasm even with the misspelling

Comment: Here it is: https://chartio.com/learn/amazon-redshift/how-to-view-permissions-in-amazon-redshift/   And I even used this earlier and it worked as far as I can remember.

Comment: You can view your grants as resolved in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741334/how-do-i-view-grants-on-redshift

Comment: Thanks @blamblam I posted an answer just to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @blamblam for pointing me to a working solution.

Moreover, I also got to know from that post, is that I did a mistake of just passing the object name whereas I need to pass the fully qualified object name (schema_name.object_name).

So, after the above change, the query looks likes this and working:

```
SELECT
    u.usename,
    t.schemaname||'.'||t.tablename,
    has_table_privilege(u.usename,t.schemaname||'.'||t.tablename,'select') AS user_has_select_permission
FROM
    pg_user u
CROSS JOIN
    pg_tables t
WHERE
    u.usename = 'userid'
```