# redshift listagg on user permission query

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using listagg to group users having same permissions, based on the query from the below stack question, tweaked it a bit for my needs.
[How do I view grants on Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741334/how-do-i-view-grants-on-redshift)

This fails saying listagg is compute node function and should be used on user created table. Any way to use listagg on catalog tables and has_*_privilege function both of which runs on leader node?

```
with cte1 as (
SELECT *
FROM 
    (    SELECT 
        fullobj
        ,usename
        ,case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'S' else '' end ||  
        case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'I' else '' end ||
        case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'U' else '' end ||
        case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'D' else '' end ||
        case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'R' else '' end AS perm
    FROM
        (
        SELECT schemaname, 't' AS obj_type, tablename AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj FROM pg_tables
        WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
        UNION
        SELECT schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, viewname AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj FROM pg_views
        WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
        ) AS objs
        ,(SELECT usename::text FROM pg_user) AS usrs
    ORDER BY fullobj
    ) WHERE perm != '')
select fullobj, perm, listagg(usename,',') from cte1 group by fullobj, perm;
SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc;
```

I tried to store the query output in a table, but its not allowing to store the table since the has_table_privilege function is leader-only function

```
create  table user_perms as
SELECT *
FROM 
    (    SELECT 
        fullobj
        ,usename
        ,case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'S' else '' end ||  
        case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'I' else '' end ||
        case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'U' else '' end ||
        case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'D' else '' end ||
        case when HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage') then 'R' else '' end AS perm
    FROM
        (
        SELECT schemaname, 't' AS obj_type, tablename AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj FROM pg_tables
        WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
        UNION
        SELECT schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, viewname AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj FROM pg_views
        WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
        ) AS objs
        ,(SELECT usename::text FROM pg_user) AS usrs
    ORDER BY fullobj
    ) WHERE perm != '';
SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

Is there any solution to this issue of being able to run listagg on leader node function/tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

As you have correctly understood, `listagg` is a function implemented by Redshift, rather than being inherited from Postgres/Paraccel, and it has been implemented only on the worker nodes.

The `has` function is from Postgres, and is implemented only on the leader-node.

The query planner will not permit a query using a leader-node only function to recruit worker nodes, so you cannot call `listagg`.

(BTW, if I remember correctly, that 'v' for reltype is also going to pick up materialized views.)

As an aside, you can in fact obtain the information you are looking for directly from the system tables, but this is a long and complex undertaking.  I am a Redshift specialist and it took me two months for the first version, although I was working at the time.

Comment: Thanks Max for the response, can you please share the version you have.

Comment: Sorry, but it's part of a product (replacement system tables) which I intend in due course to sell.